# Flex file.browseForDirectory start folder

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, file, directory

I'm using the `file.browseForDirectory()` method to make the user browse his computer and choose a folder. It's all perfect since here.
But what if I want the dialog box to already show a specific folder opened at pop up? Is it possible?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For future readers of this question - note that browseForDirectory() is only available in AIR applications, not from Flash Player running in a web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set base file url when create instance (or use resolvePath on other file) and then call browse command :

```
var file:File = new File("url/directory");
file.browseForDirectory();
```

For example , You can start browsing on desktop using code :

```
var file:File = File.desktopDirectory;
file.browseForDirectory();
```